# How do you find variable and function definitions in Anjuta?

Tags: c++, linux, ide, gnome, anjuta

Is Anjuta capable of telling you where a variable or function is first defined?

If so, how do you do it?

EDIT: Is there a way to hover over a symbol and jump to the definition like in other IDEs? For example, in netbeans you can ctrl+click a symbol and it takes you to the definition, and in KDevelop you can hover and and interactive tooltip helps you navigate to the definitions. Nothing like this in Anjuta? No plugins?

Comment: Open the Symbols left panel, then double-clicking on your desired symbol should get you closer to you goal. It's been a while since using Anjuta, but I remember well doing this move in order to track variables and method definitions. EDIT: In the menu, follow View -> Symbols

Comment: Thanks. I found that... but see my edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this seems to be the only way (unless there are unmentioned plugins):

"Open the Symbols left panel, then double-clicking on your desired symbol should get you closer to you goal. It's been a while since using Anjuta, but I remember well doing this move in order to track variables and method definitions. EDIT: In the menu, follow View -> Symbols"